# Sass Variable Value Matching from PHP (likely a Regex)

Tags: php, regex, string-matching

I need to get/set Scss variable values from PHP from a Scss variables file.

Straight to the sample:

```
// $mainColor: #fafafa;
//$mainColor : #a375c1;

$mainColor: #b3e287;

$mainColor: #ac3190;  // <- This is the value I'd like to grab/set



$boxColor: ligthen($mainColor, 10%);
```

From a file like this, (I know the variable name beforehand) I'd like to be able to get/set the variable from the 4th line, now the issue lies in that I need to ignore the variable if its commented, or afterwards if its not being assigned a value. I think the best way to acomplish this is a combination of strpos and Regex, I just don't understand enough about regex to use properly the negative lookahead, nor find the last iteration of a variable assigment.

Once I match the variable, its more than easy for me to clean/trim the value, don't need to match if is hex or not, just really grab anything between the `:` and `;`

So once again, the variable name is Known.

Comment: A per line `strpos()`, the problem is filtering out comments or non assigment statements from that, also not sure if a `strpos()` per line would perform worse than a Regex on the whole file, (although performance is not critical at all in this case).

Comment: Something like this? `$result = preg_grep("/$mainColor: (#.{6};)/", file($sass_file_path));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet is working and shows how to do most of what you are asking.

```
<?php
$contents = file('file.scss'); //array with lines from file
$linenum = 0;
foreach($contents as $key=>$line)
{
  // a line can start with 0 or more spaces, then // (maybe, maybe not), then 0 or more space, then something entirely unknown, then a : then something entirely unknown and then a ;
  //[0] = the whole line [1] = the // or not [2] is the variablename [3] = the variabel value
  if (preg_match('/[ ]*([\/]{2})?[ ]*(.*?):(.*?);/is', $line, $matches))
  {
    $variablename = $matches[2];
    $variablevalue = $matches[3];
    if ($variablename == '$myvar')
    {   
      if ($matches[1] != '//') //if it is not commented out
        $contents[$key] = '$mainColor: red;'; //replace the whole line, if you want to replace only the color you can maybe use str_replace to replace the $variablevalue to something else?
        //$contents[$key] = str_replace($variablevalue, 'red', $line); // this line is untested
      break;
    }   
  }
}

//do something with the result:
echo implode($contents);
```

Edit: I changed the script after the comment.

Comment: Will test this in a bit, not sure what the `$linenum` variable's purpose is? and asking for `$linenum == 4` is specifically looking for the 4th line, what I've provided is a sample file, which is formatted like this but much longer, the variable could be placed at any line and changed at any moment. But with this code I can probably transform it to meet my requirements.

Comment: @Sandman21dan I tought you wanted to change the variable at line 4. I changed the script in my answer to have it on any line but have the variable name match. `$linenum` was only used to get the 4th line and skip empty lines. I also tweaked the regex slightly.

Comment: This works! the one problem was the `break` statement after confirming is a variable, because it would stop the algorithm even if what was found was a comment, so from this, after assessing that the line is not a comment, I built an array of results and the last element (would contain the actual color to be used) is the one I must replace. Still, the regex works wonderfully this is very much what I wanted. Thanks!